# How to make multiple foreign keys in a table refer to different columns of the table being referrenced in django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

So i have been experimenting with django and its inbuilt databases and seem to have gotten stuck in displaying multiply foreign keys

For Example, in the flight table if a row had values like this fl_no=EK560, inbound = Dubai, dest= Tokyo, Park_bay= 7b, airline = delta, dep_time=19:50:00, arr_time=05:50:00

And in my flight status table since there are 4 foreign keys which are fl_no, park_bay, dest, dep_time. I want these 4 attributes to display their corresponding values from the flight table but instead right now for all the 4 foreign keys I get only the fl_no values as the options for each field instead of their corresponding value

the models.py being referred :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class flight(models.Model):
    fl_no =models.CharField(max_length=6,primary_key=True)
    inbound= models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    dest= models.CharField(max_length=15,blank=True)
    park_bay= models.CharField(max_length=3)
    airline= models.CharField(max_length=15)
    dep_time= models.TimeField()
    arr_time= models.TimeField()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fl_no
```

the referencing models.py:

```
from django.db import models
from postlog.models import flight

# Create your models here.
class FlightStatus(models.Model):
    Yes = 1
    No = 2
    CLEANING_CHOICES = (
        (Yes, 'Yes'),
        (No,'No'),
    )
    fl_no= models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='fli_no')
    park_bay= models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='parki_bay')
    catering= models.CharField(max_length=9)
    fuel= models.IntegerField()
    pas_cnt= models.IntegerField()
    dest= models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='desti')
    dep_time=models.ForeignKey(flight,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='dept_time')
    Cleaning = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=CLEANING_CHOICES)
```

my html code:

```
{% extends 'base_template1.html' %}
{% load static from staticfiles %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}

<!DOCTYPE html>

{% block title %} Status {% endblock %}

{% block content %} 
<button type="button" class="butra button1ra" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#Add_Modal">Add Flight Status</button>

<!-- Adding a Flight Status -->

<div class="modal fade" id="Add_Modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="Add_ModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="AddModalLabel">Flight Details</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
          <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form|crispy }}
        </form>
      </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Add Details</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

{%endblock%}
```

[all my foreign key attributes display the same values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w2LCR.png)

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.fl_no
```

I know I have to change the **str** function but im not sure how

I have used Model Forms for the forms

Comment: What do you mean by output multiple foreign key values? You need to clarify your question a little more.

Comment: sorry for the confusion. hope I have made the question a bit more understandable now